# VHDL GENERIC Multidimensional Array

Tags: generics, multidimensional-array, vhdl

I use this ENTITY :

```
ENTITY SPI_PT100 IS
GENERIC
(
    PT100_DATA_SIZE     : INTEGER := 8; --nombre de data à envoyer par trame
    PT100_NB_MOSI       : INTEGER := 3; --nombre de ligne MOSI
    PT100_10ms_CNT      : INTEGER := 400000; --nb tick in_clk entre deux trames (défaut 10ms @ 40Mhz) 
    PT100_500ns_CNT     : INTEGER := 20 --nb de tick in_clk entre deux changement d'état sur SCLK (1/2 periode) (défaut : sclk = 1Mhz)
);
PORT
(
    --input
    in_clk          : IN  STD_LOGIC; --40Mhz
    in_data         : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((PT100_DATA_SIZE-1) DOWNTO 0); --data à envoyer
    --output
    out_spi_sclk    : OUT  STD_LOGIC := '0'; --clk du SPI 
    out_spi_u_sync  : OUT STD_LOGIC := '1'; -- u_sync du SPI
    out_spi_mosi    : OUT  STD_LOGIC := '0' -- mosi du SPI
);
END ENTITY;
```

I want to use PT100_NB_MOSI as a generic multiaray size :

```
in_data : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((PT100_DATA_SIZE-1) DOWNTO 0); ==> 
in_data : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((PT100_NB_MOSI-1) DOWNTO 0)) OF ((PT100_DATA_SIZE-1) DOWNTO 0);
```

I know that I can do it using a type or a subtype but in this case I think I must use a package.
Is there a solution using only GENERIC mechanism ?

Comment: This can be done in VHDL-2008. It remains to be seen how many decades have to pass before is is supported by the tool vendors.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. What you can do is use a one-dimensional vector:

`in_data : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((PT100_NB_MOSI*PT100_DATA_SIZE-1) DOWNTO 0);`

And access `in_data(i*PT100_DATA_SIZE+j)` for accessing the `(i, j)` array element.

Else, you have to declare it in a package file as an array:

`type my_arr is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(PT100_DATA_SIZE-1 DOWNTO 0);`

Then include the array: `use work.my_pkg.my_arr;` (or `use work.my_pkg.all;` for the whole package) and use it in the interface: 
`in_data : IN my_arr((PT100_NB_MOSI-1) DOWNTO 0);`